# Send word to background process c# without SendKeys

Tags: c#, process, background, sendkeys, postmessage

I need to send world(keys) to background console program. I just found this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

    const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
    const int VK_ALT = 0x12;

    //rest
    IntPtr h = b.Client.MainWindowHandle; // handle my process
    PostMessage(h, WM_CHAR, WM_CHAR, IntPtr.Zero); // send one uint char
    keybd_event(VK_ALT, (byte)MapVirtualKey(VK_ALT, 0), 0, 0);  // send alt key up
```

My question is: how can I get keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd>? And how to convert string "XYZ" to uint?

Comment: Are you trying trying to send messages to a program you've written, or keypresses to a 3rd party program? For the first one, google for "interprocess communication"  or IPC.

Comment: Keypress to 3rd program that Im open inside Panel in form.